# getelementbyid and tagname and classname

Tags: javascript

I want to know how you can get element using pure javascript.

I have my code below:

```
        <html>
             <body>
                 <div id="abc" class="xy"> 123 </div>
                <p id="abc" class="xyz"> 123 </p>
              <span id="foo" class="foo2"> foo3 </span>
             </body>
           </html>
```

Here i want to find element with combination:

1. find element has id abc and tagname p
2. find element has id abc and classname xy
3. find element has classname foo2 and tagname span
4. find element has id abc and classname xy and tagname div

I know we can't use more than one id per page. But in worse situation is it ok to have same ID to different tags? in html?

Comment: IDs MUST be unique.

Comment: _But in worse situation is it ok to have same ID to different tags? in html?_ NO

Answer (score 12):

You can get more "advanced" selection using `querySelectorAll`. For your three examples:

1. `document.querySelectorAll("p#abc")`
2. `document.querySelectorAll(".xy#abc")`
3. `document.querySelectorAll("span.foo2")`

Comment: Just make sure to note the browser support: http://caniuse.com/queryselector Not real great with IE (what else is new? lol)

Comment: I want to use getelementsbyid by classname and bytagname.

Comment: Note that querySelectorAll is a slow routine. If you are using it on a large document or multiple times, nsure to profile your code it in jsperf. Ref: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/

Comment: @Ethan It should be noted that qSA has a higher *up-front* computation cost. However, once created, it is extremely quick to access. gEBTN on the other hand has almost no up-front cost, but is comparatively slower to access.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for your response. Can you explain a bit more, with an example probably (I am quite a novice with pure js).

Comment: It's explained in the blog article you linked, albeit briefly. The article explains how a live node list (gEBTN) is super-fast to create because it's just "ohey, I exist", but accessing it requires calculations to check the document state every time. On the other hand, a static node list (qSA) does these calculations up front, and only once. So if you're accessing it a lot, qSA will be better.

Answer (score 2):

If the IDs in the HTML aren't unique, any Javascript using them can't be guaranteed to work correctly, no matter how many browsers you test it in.

So the first two things you're looking for would use getElementById, since your IDs should be unique.

For the second, use getElementsByTagName, and loop through the results to check whether each has the required class.

Comment: Let assume we have unique ID, can you write pure js code to find these elements in all 3 scenario?

Comment: There's no difference between (1) and (2) since you don't need to worry about any other attribute once you have the ID. Use getElementById and you're done. I've provided the answer for (3). So the answer is: Yes, you can do it with pure JavaScript (though one wonders what impure JavaScript is).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this   :

**document.getElementByXXX** --> you can put Tag,Name,Calss,ID instead of **XXX**

element = document.getElementById(id);

example if you want to change bg color:

```
 window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById("your_id").style.background ="red";
}
```

here are some good examples:
http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html

**@Raj Mehta**  its working:

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script>
    function load(){


var myObj1 = document.getElementById("root").getElementsByClassName("xyz");
var myObj2 = document.getElementById("root").getElementsByClassName("xy");
var myObj3= document.getElementById("root").getElementsByClassName("foo2");
var myObj4= document.getElementById("root").getElementsByTagName("p");
var myObj5= document.getElementById("root").getElementsByTagName("div");


myObj1[0].style.color="red";
myObj2[0].style.color="green";
myObj3[0].style.color="skyblue";
myObj4[1].style.color="purple";
myObj5[1].style.color="blue";
}
</script>
</head>
       <body onload="load()" >  
         <div id="root">
                 <div id="abc" class="xy"> 123 <div> here you combine using array[0],[1],[2]... depends on you structure</div>  </div>
                 <p id="abc" class="xyz"> 123 </p>
                <span name="span" id="foo" class="foo2"> foo3 </span>
                <p id="new" name="name"> one more lvl</p>
          </div>
         </body>
       </html>
```

There is no other way either this or use jquery.

Comment: Check my question i want to find element with combination using pure js and no queryselectorall since its not fully IE friendly.

Comment: hmmm i'm not sure i understand you question. It's not good to have same id's for more tags. You can also have combination of selection like:     `document.getElementById("your_id").getElementsByTagName("tag_name")`

Comment: document.getElementById("your_id").getElementsByTagName("tag_name")   not working.

Comment: its working, i edited my answer. You must have hierarchy(DOM structure)/nodes and then you can getelementsBy... like i did in example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're OK with them having unique ids (which is required in HTML if they have ids at all), factor your HTML to this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="abc1" class="xy"> 123 </div>
        <p id="abc2" class="xyz"> 123 </p>
        <span id="foo" class="foo2"> foo3 </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then for your three different selections:

1. `document.getElementById("abc1")` gets you the `<div>` with id `abc1`.
2. `document.getElementById("abc2")` gets you the `<p>` with id `abc2`.
3. `document.getElementById("foo")` gets you the `<span>` with id `foo`.

Comment: find element has id abc and tagname p ------
    find element has id abc and classname xy -----
    find element has classname foo2 and tagname span --------
  i dont want it with just ID. i want combination of id , class and tagname.

Comment: If each one has an id there's no need to access it any other way.  `getElementById` is by far the easiest and most useful of all the functions if you're accessing items which already have ids.

Comment: @Raj: Once you have a reference to the element, you can inspect the tag name and the classes and test whether it matches your requirements.